# How can i find this datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

Python + SQlite

I try to insert this format of Datetime:

```
2022-06-17 19:59:28.982886322 -0400 EDT m=+28703.158291557
```

Whit:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timezone

datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

I can have only:

```
2022-06-18 00:11:38.637526+00:00
```

Comment: maybe you should use `.strftime()` to format string with all needed data.

Comment: What's your expected result type, a string or a datetime object? Also, how do you want to handle the monotonic clock reading ("m=+ ..."), do you need to keep this info?